# Spring MVC : autowiring a controller in another controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two controllers `LoginViewController` and `UserViewController` as

```
@Controller
public class LoginViewController {

    @Autowired
    private UserViewController userViewController;  //Can't autowire, since spring creates a proxy for UserViewController class

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=POST)
    public String login(){

        //username and password checking etc

        if(login_successfull){
            //When login successfull, i need to redirect the screen to user dashboard  
            model.addAttribute("loginMessage", "You are loggined successfully")
            return userViewController.viewDashboard(userId);
        }   
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserViewController {

    @Autowired 
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/dashboard", method=GET)
    public String viewDashboard(Model model, @RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Long userId){
        //Fetch and send user details to dashboard
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.get(userId));
        return "userDashboard"; 
    }
}
```

After successful user login, I need to redirect the screen to user dashboard with a login success message.

For this can use 2 approaches

1. Since I have a method to load user dashboard in `UserViewController`, I autowired `UserViewController` in `LoginViewController`, which leads to `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, since spring creates a proxy for `UserViewController`.
2. I can use `redirect/forward` to route to user dashboard as return `"redirect:/user/dashboard?id=123"`. But when I change the url of `viewDashboard()` method, I need to identify and correct all the `redirect/forward` statements.

So, is there any way to invoke `UserViewController.viewDashboard()` from `LoginViewController` ?
I am using spring 3.1.4 and thymeleaf

Comment: is it under the same package? try creating new constructor and call directly without autowiring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the output of a controller to send the user to another controller, you can perform a 'redirect':

```
if(login_successfull){
    //When login successfull, i need to redirect the screen to user dashboard  
    model.addAttribute("loginMessage", "You are loggined successfully")
    return "redirect:/user/dashboard";
}
```

If you decide to change the URL of your controller, you will need to replace all those HTML links in your site. If you are already doing a global search/replace, then you should be able to find the redirect instances as well.

Alternatively, you could try this:

```
public class UrlConstants {
    public static final String USER_PATH = "/user";
    public static final String DASHBOARD_PATH = "/dashboard";
}
```

Then you change your controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(UrlConstants.USER_PATH)
public class UserViewController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value=UrlConstants.DASHBOARD_PATH, method=GET)
```

And then for your redirect:

```
return "redirect:" + UrlConstants.USER_PATH + UrlConstants.DASHBOARD_PATH;
```

Comment: You can also use 
**response.sendRedirect("/user/dashboard");**
to redirect to your dashboard and obviously you need HttpServletResponse.

Comment: @Jason I have mentioned about using `redirect` in the question itself. My problem is this - when I change the request mapping url of my controller method, I have to find and replace all the `redirect` statements,  right ? Is there any other approach to achieve this, without hardcoding the request mapping url in the source code ?